# Is there any index reflecting flight ticket price trends?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, price

Following [Why are international flights so much more expensive this year (2022)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/174173/1810), I wonder: Is there any index reflecting flight ticket price trends?

I'd like to better quantify such price trends.

Comment: 10 seconds with a search engine reveals https://www.bls.gov/cpi/factsheets/airline-fares.htm, which you could have found just as easily (I literally copied and pasted your question title). They have an online database you can query. Here's another link that also came up that might help: https://www.bts.gov/air-fares

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks! I did search a bit but sometimes rephrase my query before posting here and forget to search again.

Comment: @GregHewgill ease of finding an answer is not a reason for the question necessarily being bad.

Answer (score 3):

As [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill) [commented](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174205/is-there-any-index-reflecting-flight-ticket-price-trends#comment435441_174205), the U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics [publishes](https://www.bls.gov/cpi/factsheets/airline-fares.htm) airline fare statistics, which they use in the Consumer Price Index (CPI):

> Web-based pricing enables the CPI to track a more defined trip month-to-month, where prices are collected by assigning each quote fixed specifications for advance reservation and day of the week.
>
> [image]
>
> | Year | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | HALF1 | HALF2 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2013 | 306.603 | 309.283 | 315.303 | 318.815 | 326.500 | 325.321 | 315.789 | 303.848 | 301.476 | 310.012 | 318.197 | 301.357 |  |  |
> | 2014 | 291.836 | 297.679 | 302.464 | 318.331 | 341.947 | 342.697 | 315.012 | 295.609 | 292.397 | 301.466 | 305.885 | 287.175 |  |  |
> | 2015 | 283.152 | 288.626 | 287.362 | 294.603 | 319.401 | 324.953 | 297.324 | 277.768 | 274.897 | 285.837 | 294.143 | 278.658 |  |  |
> | 2016 | 278.334 | 283.520 | 283.584 | 295.909 | 309.540 | 309.679 | 283.501 | 268.040 | 267.457 | 270.922 | 274.761 | 265.436 |  |  |
> | 2017 | 269.241 | 280.517 | 283.583 | 294.034 | 300.609 | 296.384 | 276.308 | 259.359 | 259.143 | 267.297 | 267.970 | 254.947 |  |  |
> | 2018 | 255.496 | 265.272 | 267.482 | 273.817 | 280.804 | 278.937 | 264.994 | 255.877 | 258.196 | 265.930 | 263.809 | 248.290 | 270.301 | 259.516 |
> | 2019 | 248.433 | 259.049 | 259.698 | 268.767 | 283.275 | 283.001 | 268.314 | 259.849 | 263.149 | 269.871 | 268.994 | 252.411 | 267.037 | 263.765 |
> | 2020 | 255.200 | 265.142 | 232.113 | 203.342 | 201.649 | 206.066 | 204.785 | 199.496 | 197.424 | 215.993 | 223.360 | 205.983 | 227.252 | 207.840 |
> | 2021 | 200.825 | 197.204 | 197.134 | 222.953 | 250.209 | 256.684 | 243.613 | 212.882 | 198.975 | 205.994 | 215.159 | 208.954 | 220.835 | 214.263 |
> | 2022 | 210.762 | 222.227 | 243.689 | 297.143 | 344.853 | 344.101 | 311.205 | 283.911 | 284.313 | 294.340 | 292.656 | 268.519 | 277.129 | 289.157 |
> | 2023 | 264.629 | 281.216 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

[Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill)  also pointed to a [webpage](https://www.bts.gov/air-fares) by the US Bureau of Transportation Statistics that also contains statistics on airfares.